# How can i create a function to search for a keywords and words like it that are input by a user?

Tags: sql, function, sql-like, psql

Heres my code.

```
create function keyword_search(text)
    returns setof prodincat as

$$
    select
        products.id,
        title,
        author,
        publisher,
        year,
        description,
        price,
        case
            when qty >= 1 then 'Y'
            when qty = 0 then 'N'
            end as in_stock,
        catid as categor_id,
        major as cat_name,
        minor as subcat_name
    from
        products
        join categories on ( products.catid = categories.id )
    where
        products.id = '%'+ $1 +'%'
        or
        title like '%'+ $1 +'%'
        or
        author like '%'+ $1 +'%'
        or
        description like '%'+ $1 +'%';
$$
    language sql;
```

My problem is with searching for words like $1. right now it gives me the error

> operator does not exist: unknown + text

so i cannot add '%' onto $1 and both %$1% and '%$1%' dont work as well. just using $1 works fine but i need to be able to search for words and sentences that include just one letter or word.

Comment: What is $1? A variable? Shouldn't you use text there?

Comment: @President `$1` is the parameter - it's an alternative notation, rather than naming the parameters you can refer to them as `$1`, `$2` etc.

Comment: Michael the concatenation operator in postgres is not `+` [but `||`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html)